# Python Echo Function

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

I am currently learning about python functions.  In the book I'm reading "Introducing Python" it lists the below code as an example.  The purpose of the function is to simply output word twice.  I'm drawing a blank as to what I'm doing incorrectly.  This is not the only example in the book where I receive a syntax error.  I'm assuming it has something to do with my indentation?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance!

```
 >>> def echo(anything):
 ...     return anything '' anything
 ...     
  File "<input>", line 2
    return anything '' anything
                 ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: try `anything + ' ' + anything` or `anything * 2`

Comment: Thank you.  I'll give it a shot right now.  Just found it odd that the examples in the book didn't compile correctly.  I copied them right from it haha.

Comment: Priyesh, you're the man.  Thank you so much.  All solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a list returned, do:

```
return any, '', any
```

If it is returning a list, you can stick it in separate variables with:

```
a,b,c = echo(anything)
```

Comment: This returns a `tuple`, not a list.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yup, it's a tuple. My bad. Thanx Juanpa